# How to sync changed files only with Dropbox using dropbox-uploader.sh?

Tags: sync, dropbox

How to sync changed files only with Dropbox using dropbox-uploader.sh?

Hello,

I want to know how to sync changed files on my local machine using dropbox-uploader.sh by Andrea Fabrizi.

Let's say I edit a text file locally (test.txt).

I want dropbox-uploader.sh to upload that changed file and only that file automatically to Dropbox. I guess automatically scan a folder recursively for changed files every x minutes or a similar approach.

Can it be done and if so how?

Ubuntu 17.10

Vesa

Comment: Isn't it the case that any changed file saved into your local Dropbox folder is automatically synced to your Dropbox account?

Comment: Using Dropbox yes but in this case I am using the dropbox-uploader.sh script, see above. This is an ARM machine and ordinary Dropbox does not work in this environment.

Comment: ok, now understood.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your file is under `/home/vesa/test.txt` and the script location is `/home/vesa/dropbox_uploader.sh` You can run the upload manually by

```
/home/vesa/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/vesa/test.txt .
```

The dot mean at the end is root folder in Dropbox.

You can set the automatically upload in crontab. It will upload the `test.txt` file in every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/vesa/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/vesa/test.txt .
```

More commands and parameters are available on [GitHub page](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader).